# Integrating Cloud Gateway API with GKE

Tags: kubernetes

I am looking for a working example/tutorial on how I can use Google Cloud API Gateway with microservices/API hosted in GKE.  For example when I try to create an API Gateway and I point it to an existing API on GKE I get the following error:

Backend URL "http://35.xxx.xxx.xxx/legalentities" is forbidden: cannot route requests by IP Address.

Comment: Looks like it was answered at [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889684)

Answer (score 0):

This case [was answered on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64909558/12428794) by *@Ali Nahid*.

GKE by default produces ip address for ingress controller or load balancer and API Gateway does not allow ip address to be hostname for x-google-backend. This is a problem, hopefully it will be resolved the API Gateway comes out for beta.

I faced the same situation. This is how I got around to it (using nip.io):

```
/products/getoptions:
    get:
      summary: get product options
      operationId: getProductOptions
      x-google-backend:
        address: https://35.xxx.xxx.xxx.nip.io/api/productservice
        path_translation: APPEND_PATH_TO_ADDRESS
      parameters:
        - name: x-access-token
          in: header
          description: Access Token
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: x-refresh-token
          in: header
          description: Refresh Token
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          schema:
            type: object
```